# Дополнительное поле из другой таблицы в MySQL-выборке

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такая задача.

Существует две таблицы. Допусти `user(id, email)` и `bid(id, title, id_user).` Связь между таблицами по `id_user`. Нужно получить все записи `user` + сделать динамически дополнительное поле пусть будет `isset`, который будет проверять есть ли `id` в таблице `bid - id_user`. Если есть то значение будет 1, если нету то 0.

Как сделать такой запрос? Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом, соединить таблицы `LEFT JOIN`, в результате вы выберете все записи из таблицы `user`, которым по связи будет сопоставлена одна из записей таблицы `bid`. Если запись сопоставить не получится, то будет возвращено значение `NULL`. Превратить его в 0 или 1 можно при помощи оператора `IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT
  user.id AS id,
  user.email AS email,
  bid.id IS NOT NULL AS isset
FROM
  user
LEFT JOIN
  bid
ON
  user.id = bid.user_id
```

Comment: уау, круто спасибо сильно помогли))) Приму ответ через 5 минут

Comment: Только еще вопрос а как два условия написать вот типо того  vc.users_email IS NOT NULL AS isset, vcity.users_email IS NOT NULL AS isset1 выдает ошибку!

Comment: @duddeniska А что за алиасы vc и vcity? Вы хотите создать поле-флаг из двух полей vc.users_email IS NOT NULL AND vcity.users_email IS NOT NULL AS isset1 или хотите получить два поля-флага?

Comment: да хочу получить два поля флага! из разных таблиц. vc это одна таблица, а vcity другая таблица. Вы пример сделали из одной таблицы, а у меня их две. Спасибо!

Comment: @duddeniska Тогда ваш вариант должен работать, а что за ошибку выдает? Можете привести ее текст?

Comment: в phpmyAdmin пишит: Неизвестное ключевое слово(около is), Неизвестное ключевое слово(около NOT NULL), Неизвестное ключевое слово(около AS), неизвестный токе (isset). И так же со вторым. Не понятно почему!

Comment: @duddeniska Если не сложно, приведите как сейчас выглядит ваш запрос?

Comment: SELECT u.id, u.email, u.date, iu.type, iu.title, iu.address, iu.phone, iu.mobile, iu.skype, 
        vc.users_email IS NOT NULL AS isset, vcity.users_email IS NOT NULL AS isset1
        FROM users u
        LEFT JOIN info_users iu ON iu.id_users = u.id
        LEFT JOIN vehicle_country vc ON  u.email = vc.users_email
        LEFT JOIN vehicle_city vcity ON  u.email = vcity.users_email
        ORDER BY u.date DESC

Comment: Простите не могу отформатировать

Comment: @duddeniska а если все-таки нажать выполнить запрос - он выполняется? phpMyAdmin и мне подсвечивает запрос, но мне кажется он просто неправильно его разбирает - MySQL нормально ответ отдает.

Comment: хм прикольно да выполняется, вот только на сервере php Не выполняется, просто не открывается страница

Comment: Почему то не нравится что 3 left join. один любой убираю все работает!

Comment: @duddeniska, смотрите уже в логах что не так, будут трудности - заводите новый запрос. Чем сможем - поможем.

Comment: Тогда уж INNER JOIN.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр В вопросе указано "Нужно получить все записи user", в вашем варианте отсекутся записи, для для которых нет связи с другой таблицей.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте оператор IF():

```
SELECT
    user.id,
    user.email,
    IF(user.id=bid1.id_user,1,0) AS isset1,
    IF(user.id=bid2.id_user,1,0) AS isset2
FROM
    user
LEFT JOIN bid1 ON bid1.id_user=user.id
LEFT JOIN bid2 ON bid2.id_user=user.id
```

Учитывая ваши уточнения в комментариях, замените bid1 и bid2 на vc и vcity соответственно.